# I need a gap between checkbox and name of checkbox in gwt

Tags: javascript, html, css, gwt

I need Gap between checkbox and content in gwt

```
checkbox c=new checkbox("checkme");
c.setStyleName("checkbox_style");
```

If i am using padding or margin the entire checkbox and its content is moving.  I need a gap between checkbox and "checkme"

Answer (score 0):

You have to match the `input` or the `label` in your CSS selector:

```
.checkbox_style input { margin-right: 15px; }
```

Comment: thanq will u please tell me in gwt

Comment: "In gwt" ?! CSS is CSS, whether with GWT or not.

Comment: thanq so much Thomas Its Working successfully

Comment: I need a gap and at the same time I want to shift only content to top not the checkbox.If i write both margin-right and margin-bottom only for margin-right content is moving and for margin-bottom entire checkbox and content is moving top.Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to make checkboxes consistent across different browsers:

```
.gwt-CheckBox {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 6px;
    padding-left: 26px;
    text-indent: -26px;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
    height: 13px;
    margin: 0 6px;
    *overflow: hidden;
    width: 13px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> this will help you try it

JQuery.select(element).css("margin-right","10px");